# GroupBox Header Not Showing

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I followed an this [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3883955/wpf-itemscontrol-itemtemplate-border-with-groupstyle) question, which has a link to another article, on how to group data, but my header is not showing. Can someone point me to the problem of why my header is not showing in the grouping of my data. The only thing different between the article and my markup that I see is that my data is in a different format, but I have no control on how I receive it.

Representation of my data:

```
<MyDetails xmlns="clr-namespace:MyCompany.Mapping;assembly=Mapping" xmlns:scg="clr-
    namespace:System.Collections.Generic;assembly=mscorlib" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <MyDetails.Details>
        <scg:List x:TypeArguments="MyAttributes" Capacity="64">
            <MyAttributes Bit="0" Channel="1" Name="SomeName" IOAttribute="O" />
        </scg:List>
    </MyDetails.Details>
</MyDetails>
```

ViewModel Property I bind to:

```
ObservableCollection<MyDetails> Channels= new 
ObservableCollection<MyDetails>();
```

MyDetails Class Public Property (Defined as a DataMember):

```
List<MyAttributes> Details = new List<MyAttributes>();
```

MyAttributes Class Public Properties (All defined as a DataMembers):

```
property string Channel {get; set;}
property string Bit {get; set;}
property string Name {get; set;}
property string Attribute {get; set;}
```

XAML Resource Header:

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="MyDetails" Source="{Binding Channels[0].Details}">
    <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
        <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Channel" />
    </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
</CollectionViewSource>
```

XAML:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyDetails}}">
<ItemsControl.GroupStyle>
    <GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                            <GroupBox Margin="10" >
                                <GroupBox.Header>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Channel}" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="16" /> <!-- Does not show -->
                                </GroupBox.Header>
                                <ItemsPresenter />
                            </GroupBox>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
    </GroupStyle>
</ItemsControl.GroupStyle>
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Bit}" Width="50" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Width="150" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Attribute}" Width="50" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DataContext` against each `GroupItem` will be of [`CollectionViewGroup`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewgroup(v=vs.110).aspx) type which contains information about each group like `Items` or `Name`. You need to change binding in a group header to [`Name`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewgroup.name(v=vs.110).aspx) which will be the value grouped by

```
<GroupBox.Header>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="16" />
</GroupBox.Header>
```

Comment: That worked. I can see the header and it is the Channel I want to see. What I don't understand is why you had me put Name in for the binding since I want to group on Channel. Can you explain to me what I missed?

Comment: I've added a bit more description. Hope it explains more

Comment: Ok...I think I understand. I thought it was a property of my data that had to go in there, but it is a property of the CollectionViewGroup that I defined in the <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions> section of my XAML. Right?