# How to add formatted Subgroup and Group Total in TreeView or HederedItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core, treeview, headereditemscontrol

Initially I wanted to do it with `ItemsControl` but I couldn't think of anything other than using one `ItemsControl` for each group (Non Current Assets, Current Assets, etc.). To reduce the complexity I've used `TreeView` instead to present the information and with that here's how it looks:

[image]

Not bad! What I want now is to add sub group total for each **Bold** head and two group total: one for Non Current Assets and Current Assets and another for Non Current Liabilities, Current Liabilities and Fund. Here's the xaml for the `TreeView`:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding BalanceSheet}"
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
        ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
        BorderThickness="0">
    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="TreeViewItem">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header" 
                                            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
                            <ItemsPresenter Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" 
                                        Name="ItemsHost"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Ledgers}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Book}" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="14"/>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <DockPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Ledger}"/>
                        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                                Text="{Binding Amount, StringFormat='N0'}"/>
                    </DockPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

and the Data Structures:

```
List<Balances> balanceSheet;
public List<Balances> BalanceSheet { get => balanceSheet; set { balanceSheet = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } }

public class Balances
{
    public string Book { get; set; }
    public List<Balance> Ledgers { get; set; }
    public Balances()
    {
        Ledgers = new List<Balance>();
    }
}

public class Balance
{
    public string Book { get; set; }
    public string Ledger { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }
}
```

Is it possible to use `HeaderedItemsControl` instead of `Treeview`? I haven't seen any good example of `HeaderedItemsControl` to work with.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3883955/wpf-itemscontrol-itemtemplate-border-with-groupstyle

Comment: @ASh, sub grouping done. After looking at a few examples I've used an IvalueConverter to compute the subgroup sum from `CollectionViewSource`. Now stuck at the grouping of subgroups eg. Total of Assets.

Comment: It was as simple as just adding one more property as group descriptor to get grouping of subgroups, great!